# Calculating Percentile Rank Using Relative Strength Ranking

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I have a spreadsheet of stock quotes that contains Relative Strength Ranking (RSR) ranging from -45 to 65 and the count of ranks is 1500. Could someone please explain how I can calculate percentile ranks using these numbers? Is there a specific formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the total number of stocks is exactly 1500, the [percentile rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile_rank)is $\frac {(\text {number below + number tied/2)}100}{1500}$.  So if a stock has 579 stocks with lower RSR and 44 with the same RSR, its percentile rank is $\frac {(579 + 44/2)100}{1500}=\frac{60100}{1500}\approx 40.06$.  Some people then round to the nearest whole number, or truncate, or something like that.

Comment: Many thanks, Ross. I looked around trying to understand other formulas but they didn't seem to contain the "number tied". Having the number of tied stocks makes the result much better.